# How create another partition automated using all free space?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have fresh installation linux from certified image,
and I would like to create automated script to create another partion using all free space.

In my current situation I have 60GB disk and 47GB free space,
But I would like to create universal script to create another partition (disk size can be different)
How to do it ?

To create new partition in non-interactive mode I need to know start-end sector, correct ?
is there any option with sfdisk/parted  to just create new partition ?

Workaround can be sfdisk -F  /dev/sda,to get start-end sectors,  but I have to parse somehow this.

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x32082de6

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1026047  1024000  500M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1026048 25602047 24576000 11.7G 8e Linux LVM

# sfdisk -F  /dev/sda
Unpartitioned space /dev/sda: 47.8 GiB, 51316260864 bytes, 100227072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Start       End   Sectors  Size
25602048 125829119 100227072 47.8G
```

Comment: Create a universal script? Why? In what circumstances? Are you trying to develop a product that can always create a new partition?

Comment: not exactly product... :)  but yes I have received task in my job to fix certified images to be complied by customers hardening checks (e.g. separate FS /var/log/audit etc.. so I need more free space).

Comment: Got it. You need to do more research and come up with a clearer, more specific question, a single question.